# Undefined is returned from appended array

Tags: javascript, arrays, post, scripting

I currently POST to my script:

```
process : edit
r1_person : 00008
r2_person : 00009
persons : 2
```

Which my script accepts:

```
    if (process == 'edit') {
        var persons_array = [];
        for (i = 0; i < persons; i++) {
            var test_push = pnvl(request.getParameter('r' + i + '_person'))
            persons_array.push(test_push);
            response.write(persons_array[i] + '\n');
        }
    }
```

I get back:

undefined
undefined

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:

Solution: response.write() will not return correctly inside a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 pnvl(request.getParameter(eval('r' + i + '_person')))
```

Comment: JS says: "r1_person" is not defined.

I need the parameter value, not the actual string r1_person.

Answer (score 0):

you iterate from 0 to 1, you want this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= persons; i++)
```

Comment: I was using r1 as an example, r0 doesn't work, either.